# Is it possible to retrieve HTML code from a word document paragraph using OpenXML or Microsoft.Interop? C#

Tags: c#, html, ms-word, interop, openxml

There exists a way to get HTML code from a paragraph using clipboard. If you select a fragment of a document and copy it, you are able to get HTML data using C#.

```
var foo = Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.Html);
```

Unfortunately it does not meet my criteria. The perfect solution would be to open Word Document using OpenXML library, iterate through paragraphs and create HTML code for each of them.

```
using (WordprocessingDocument wordDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filePath, true))
{
  var wordDocumentBody = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body;
  foreach(var paragraph in wordDocumentBody.Descendants<Paragraph>())
  {
    if(paragraph.MeetsCriteria()) //Imaginary function that checks if paragraph has important information
      //Ideal scenario
      var paragraphHTML = paragraph.GenerateHTML();
  }
}
```

I am not interested in converting whole word document into HTML since it would be impossible to differentiate the paragraphs that I am interested in from the others.

If you have any ideas how to generate HTML for single paragraphs using mentioned libraries please let me know below.

Comment: Your question isn't clear to me.  You want to pick an arbitrary paragraph out of a Word document and then convert it to the same HTML that  Word renders to the clipboard with a user presses `<Ctrl>+C`.  Is that correct?  My gut tells me that you will likely end up disappointed, but Word does seem to have an uncountable number of features.  How does your initial example (of a user manually selecting a paragraph, copying it and then you retrieving the data as HTML) not _meet [your] criteria_?

Comment: If you have tens or hundreds of word documents, it would be pointless to do it using <Ctrl>+C. That's why I am looking for automated way of doings this. If you click Ctrl+C and it stores html data, why would it be impossible to do similar process, but instead of storing this in the clipboard, I could store it in the object and then easily get html property?

Comment: That's a very good point.  My point is that you should include that _criterion_ in your question.  Word has a zillion features, one is that it is capable of converting a clipboard selection into an HTML clipboard object.  I suspect that the only way you'll be able to do that is to automate Word to do the operation you are talking about.  The problem with that is that you can only do that from desktop Word, not on a server (you don't specify that criterion either).  There may be a way, but I'd be surprised.

Comment: Thank you. Anyway just wanted to mention why I would like to avoid using Clipboard. This is because I am going this method asynchronously. The problem with this approach was that I could not solve the STA thread mode problem and sometimes I was getting errors that something could not be copied to clipboard even if the same thing was copied successfully in the previous runs. Last thing according to your answer is that I am not using any servers, everything is being done from the level of user's desktop and the disk, using WPF application

Comment: Yup, if you are using the clipboard, it needs to be on the desktop, in an STA.  Set it up, let it run minimized slowly put-putting through your documents (consider using a Notification Area (aka System Tray) icon as part of your primary UI.) The problem is that the magic that Word uses to render the HTML is inside Word.  I don't know of any other tool that does that rendering (not that my knowledge is that extensive in this area).

Comment: It uses interop and has to create a file, but how about using the Range.ExportFragment method?

Comment: @jonsson That's a great method unfortunately I have not known this one before. I will give it a go and keep you updated.